# Relation between constexpr and pure functions

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Am I right, that:

- Any function defined with `constexpr` is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and
- Any pure function can be and must be defined with `constexpr` if it's not very expensive for compiler.

And if so, why arent `<cmath>`'s functions defined with `constexpr` ?

Comment: Even with the relaxed `constexpr` requirements, `<cmath>` functions can't be `constexpr` because they modify the global variable `errno`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add to what others have said, consider the following `constexpr` function template:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T add(T x, T y) { return x + y; }
```

This `constexpr` function template is usable in a constant expression in some cases (e.g., where `T` is `int`) but not in others (e.g., where `T` is a class type with an `operator+` overload that is not declared `constexpr`).

`constexpr` does not mean that the function is *always* usable in a constant expression, it means that the function *may* be usable in a constant expression.

(There are similar examples involving nontemplate functions.)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the previous answers: constexpr on a function restricts
its implementation greatly: its body must be visible to the compiler
(inline), and must consist only of a single return statement.  I'd be
surprised if you could implement sqrt() or sin() correctly and still
meet that last condition.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't know about it. Thanks and +1 :)

Comment: I presume things like this are valid: "constexpr int fact(int n) { return (n != 0 ? fact(n - 1) * n : 1); }" so whilst it might be tricky to implement sqrt() and sin() in terms of constexpr, I think it is certainly possible.

Comment: @Clinton 7 You have a point: recursion is allowed (intentionally, or by oversight?).  So an implementation should be possible, as long as the recursion is bound by the input argument.  (You couldn't, for example, recurse until the difference between the two approximations was less than a given value.)  But it certainly wouldn't look like the usual sqrt or sin implementation.

Comment: @James: Principally, you can express every loop with recursion, and state can be "conserved" using function arguments, so the set of `constexpr` functions is turing complete. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church-Turing_thesis . As a maybe interesting note, have a look at http://gitorious.org/metatrace , a complete compile time ray tracer, which among other things also has square root computation and ray/sphere and ray/plane intersection computation. sin/cos haven't been harmed, though.

Answer (score 9):

`constexpr` functions are not `pure` because the `constexpr` is a hint to the compiler that the function may be computed during the compilation *if* its arguments are constants *and* the operation mentionned in the body of the function, for these arguments, are themselves `constexpr`.

The latter, using template code, allows us to demonstrate an impure `constexpr` function:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T add(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
```

instantiated with this type

```
DebugInteger operator+(DebugInteger lhs, DebugInteger rhs) {
  printf("operator+ %i %i", lhs._value, rhs._value);
  return DebugInteger(lhs._value + rhs._value);
}
```

Here, the `operator+` is not constexpr, and may thus read/write global state.

We could say that a `constexpr` function is `pure` when evaluated at compilation time... but then it's simply replaced by a constant as far as the runtime is concerned.

Comment: A template function is really a family of functions, and in your example, any member of the family that is impure is also, necessarily, not constexpr.

Comment: @HighCommander4: the function *is* marked with `constexpr` (the keyword), it just does not end up being a constant expression for some cases. I would avoid conflating *constant expression* (the term of art) with `constexpr` (the C++ keyword). My point was that `constexpr` on templates was valid even though some instanciations may not end up being usable in *constant expressions*.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I disagree. You have written a template and requested `constexpr` on it. Upon specialisation, the compiler then honors that request, iff it can. You cannot say that the function is marked with constexpr, because a function template is not a function. That'd be like saying that `std::forward()` takes its argument by rvalue reference, whereas the sole purpose of `std::forward()` is to take the argument by either rvalue or lvalue reference, depending on the template argument.

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz: (Not 100% certain, but…) I think the correct term is instantiation, not specialisation.

Answer (score -1):

Every `constexpr` function is pure, but not every pure function can or should be `constexpr`.

[Examples involving `constexpr` function templates are misleading, since function templates are not functions, they're patterns by which the compiler can generate functions. The outcome of function templates, their specialisations, *are* functions and they *will* be `constexpr` iff possible.]

A pure function is one that only depends on its arguments, or other constant state. That's pretty much what a `constexpr` function is. In addition, `constexpr` functions must be defined (not only declared) prior to their first use (recursion seems to be allowed, though), and must consist of only the return statement. That's enough to make the allowed subset Turing-complete, but the result is not necessarily the most efficient form at runtime.

Which brings us to the mathematical functions. You can probably implement `constexpr` `sqrt()` or `sin()`, but they would have to use a recursive implementation that the compiler can evaluate at compile-time, whereas at runtime, these would be better implemented in one assembler operation. Since `constexpr` uses of `sqrt()` and `sin()` are few and far apart, its better to maximise runtime performance instead, which requires a form that isn't `constexpr`able.

You may wonder why you can't write one `constexpr` version of a function and one that's used at runtime, and I'd agree that would be nice to have, but the standard says you can't overload on `constexpr`ness. Maybe in C++17...

Comment: Not every `constexpr` function is pure. It's permissible for a constexpr function to do anything at all, so long as there exists a set of arguments to it which cause a pure execution.

Comment: @RichardSmith: since the definition of a pure function is that it only depends on constants and its arguments, and doesn't cause visible side effects, I don't see how changing the arguments can change pureness of a function. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @mmutz Consider `int n; constexpr int f(bool b) { return b ? 0 : (n *= getc()); }`. This is legal, because `f` produces a constant expression when given the argument `true`. But `f` is obviously not a pure function.

Comment: @Richard if the argument is false, that function call is not a constant expression.

Comment: @Ayxan I agree, but that's not relevant to the question. `f` is a `constexpr` function and is not pure, therefore not all `constexpr` functions are pure.