# Why isn't constexpr implied when applicable?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

These should probably be in different questions, but they're related so...

1. **Why do we need to write `constexpr` at all? Given a set of restrictions couldn't a compiler evaluate code to see if it satisfies the `constexpr` requirements, and treat it as `constexpr` if it does?** As a purely documentation keyword I'm not sure it holds up because I can't think of a case where I (the user of someone else's `constexpr` function) should really care if it's run time or not.

   Here's my logic: If it's an expensive function I think as a matter of good practice I should treat it as such regardless of whether I give it compile-time constant input or not. That might mean calling it during load time and saving off the result, instead of calling it during a critical point in the execution. The reason is because `constexpr` doesn't actually guarantee to me that it will not be executed in run time in the first place — so perhaps a new/different mechanism should do that.
2. **The [`constexpr` restrictions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) seem to exclude *many, if not most,* functions from being compile-time evaluated which logically could be.** I've read this is at least in part (or perhaps wholly?) to prevent infinite looping and hanging the compiler. But, if this is *the* reason, is it legitimate?

Shouldn't a compiler be able to compute if, for any given `constexpr` function with the given inputs used, it loops infinitely? This is *not* solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for *any* input. The input to a `constexpr` function is compile time constant and finite, so the compiler only has to check for infinite looping for a finite set of input: the input actually used. **It should be a regular compilation error if you write a compile-time infinite loop.**

Comment: 2) As the compiler algorithm don't know your inputs and your constexpr functions in advance it is the halting problem for the compiler. Exactly

Comment: The halting problem is exactly: Given a program and the input for that program determine if program execution for that input halts.

Comment: "It should be a regular compilation error if you write a compile-time infinite loop." This is the problem, there is no general purpose algorithm for determining if it's an infinite loop other than running it. And that takes infinite time if it is...

Comment: 1) The compiler ability to calculate different functions at compile time may vary from compiler to compiler. constexpr requirements are some common denominator: declaring constexpr the programmer force the compiler to check standard requirements even the expression is not actually used in the code (for example, library writer may provide the expression exclusively for library user)

Answer (score 2):

I asked a very similar question, [Why do we need to mark functions as constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472359/why-do-we-need-to-mark-functions-as-constexpr)

When [I pressed](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/nrAu_YbCbYM/0eQsx6ip1DwJ) Richard Smith, a Clang author, he explained:

> The constexpr keyword does have utility.
>
> It affects when a function template specialization is instantiated (constexpr function template specializations may need to be instantiated if they're called in unevaluated contexts; the same is not true for non-constexpr functions since a call to one can never be part of a constant expression). If we removed the meaning of the keyword, we'd have to instantiate a bunch more specializations early, just in case the call happens to be a constant expression.
>
> It reduces compilation time, by limiting the set of function calls that implementations are required to try evaluating during translation. (This matters for contexts where implementations are required to try constant expression evaluation, but it's not an error if such evaluation fails -- in particular, the initializers of objects of static storage duration.)

This all didn't seem convincing at first, but if you work through the details, things do unravel without `constexpr`. A function need not be instantiated until it is ODR-used, which essentially means used at runtime. What is special about `constexpr` functions is that they can violate this rule and require instantiation anyway.

Function instantiation is a recursive procedure. Instantiating a function results in instantiation of the functions and classes it uses, regardless of the arguments to any particular call.

If something went wrong while instantiating this dependency tree (potentially at significant expense), it would be difficult to swallow the error. Furthermore, class template instantiation can have runtime side-effects.

Given an argument-dependent compile-time function call in a function signature, overload resolution may incur instantiation of function definitions merely auxiliary to the ones in the overload set, including the functions that don't even get called. Such instantiations may have side effects including ill-formedness and runtime behavior.

It's a corner case to be sure, but bad things can happen if you don't require people to opt-in to `constexpr` functions.

As for `constexpr` objects, certain types can produce *core constant expressions* which are usable in constant expression contexts without having been declared `constexpr`. But you don't really want the compiler to try evaluating every single expression at compile time. That's what constant propagation is for. On the other hand it seems pretty essential to document when something *needs* to happen at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

[Note, I totally changed my answer]

To answer your second question, there are two cases for the compiler here:

1. The compiler has to be able to handle *any* arbitrary `constexpr` function(s). In this case you still have the halting problem because the set of inputs is all combinations of `constexpr` functions and calls to them.
2. The compiler can handle a finite set of `constexpr` function(s). In this case the compiler can in fact determine whether some programs will result in infinite loops, while other programs will be uncompilable (since they aren't in the set of valid inputs).

So presumably the restrictions are in place so that it satisfies case 2 for a reasonable amount of compiler effort.

Comment: You can use non-constexpr arguments with constexpr functions, you just don't get compile-time execution.

Answer (score 0):

There are both technical and ideological reasons behind this decision.

- Not always do we want `constexpr` ourselves by default - it can take
  too much compiling time. That's first.  Just imagine you implemented
  `isPrime` function and you have 100 calls with big constexpr 
  values passed in. I think you don't (in most cases) want to make
  compiler compiling this for a couple of minutes longer because it
  decided that you need those values in compile-time by itself. But if
  it's exactly the case - specify `constexpr` modifier manually. And this adds the next point:
- backward compatibility - it's unwise to assume that every possible C++98 program author who converted this program to C++11 wants`constexpr`.
- The second point is that deciding if the function can be `constexpr`
  would take compiling time by itself. And if it was trying to do that for every possible function it would take some additional time overhead. Even more, often compiler
  couldn't decide if the given function can be constexpr at all, so
  your first assumption is not correct.

Comment: On your first point, I've been mulling it over for a while and I don't think I agree. I do always want constexpr when it could be done, but I want a compiler smart enough to cache results between compiles and not have to recompute constexpr functions unless they or their input changed.

Comment: @Dave, OK, I can believe you, but this is not the case with everyone else. Certainly, there are cases when you wouldn't want this by default. And the last point: backward compatibility - it's unwise to assume that everyone who ported C++98 program to C++11 want constexpr by default.

Comment: I think my question should've been: 1) Is `constexpr` _just_ an optimization hint & documentation keyword? 2) Is this unprecedented in the language? 3) Does a keyword which is _purely_ for documentation and/or hinting to the compiler to optimize belong in C++?

Comment: As an optimization, compilers should just include a flag to turn it on and off. Those that don't want the compilation cost can turn it off just like they can turn off other optimizations at the compiler level. As a documentation keyword I can only see it being useful for knowing what you can use in places that _need_ a compile time constant (like switch cases, etc). Even then, a decent IDE could tell you that without the keyword.

Comment: `constexpr` is not a hint - it's a strong guarantee that a value will be calculated in compile-time and that's it's primary and only purpose. But this guarantee can be used not only for optimizations but also for cases where language requires constexpr values (e.g. array size: `int arr[g()]` will work only if g is `constexpr` function).

Comment: It's not a strong guarantee, you can use non-`constexpr` variables with them. As for the cases when you _need_ a compile time constant: If the standard said that methods which meet the constexpr requirements must be able to be used as compile time constants, that would be equivalent, but it would be slightly annoying for people to quickly see if `int arr[g()]` is going to compile successfully or not (unless an IDE told you so). Still, that's just documentation...

Comment: @Dave, sorry, of course, I meant this is a strong guarantee *if and only if* you pass `constexpr` arguments inside.