# Is array::operator[] actually noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, noexcept

Per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at), the overloads are not currently `noexcept` specified. But I think they are actually `noexcept`, right? Since

1. No bounds checking is performed. So no `out_of_range` exception like [`array::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).
2. If input is beyond bounds, low-level segfault or access violation happens, which is beyond C++ exception scope (I guess).

Comment: In libc++  `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX14
    reference operator[](size_type __n)             {return __elems_[__n];}` compared to, say: `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX14
    iterator begin() _NOEXCEPT {return iterator(data());}` . Why do you doubt cppref?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't constexpr implied when applicable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877057/why-isnt-constexpr-implied-when-applicable)

Comment: Interestingly, [`libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array;hb=HEAD) does appear to mark both `operator []` methods as `noexcept`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that `operator[]` is not marked as `noexcept` is that it has a "narrow contract", i.e, the index value is required to be in the range `0 ... N-1`. If the value passed is not in that range, the behavior is not defined, and (who knows?) the function might throw.

The standard is pretty consistent about not marking things with "narrow contracts" as noexcept. This is informally known as "the Lakos rule".

Note that library IMPLEMENTERS have the freedom to add `noexcept` where the standard does not specify it, if they choose. I'll think about adding that to libc++.

[Later: It turns out that libc++ does this already for `string` and `string_view`, but not `vector`, `array` or `deque`]

[Sill later: libc++ now marks `operator[]` as noexcept for `vector`/`array` and `deque`.]

Comment: What's the reasoning behind "*the Lakos Rule*"? As I understood (for exmaple from Scott Meyers' presentations, but I can't find the link right now), `noexcept` functions may as well break (throw or invoke UB) but if they break, that implies that the whole program cannot recover from such state. That's what Undefined Behaviour does - the program is undefined and you cannot recover. What the reasoning behind distinguishing these two? Is `noexcept` then considered as *it will **neither** throw **nor** invoke UB*?

Comment: @Fureeish not marking a function with restrictions noexcept allows an implementer to define that it *will throw*, rather than any other symptom of UB, which allows tests for that case to be in-process (otherwise the test harness must detect that what it is testing `std::terminate`d)

Comment: @Caleth how can an implementer define it to throw something when the standard says nothing about it throwing anything?

Comment: @Fureeish because the standard says that *anything* is allowed.

Comment: @Caleth can you provide a quote from the standard that states that whether `operator []` throws is implementation defined? What do you mean by "the standard says that *anything* is allowed"?

Comment: @Fureeish that's what undefined behaviour *means*. "behavior for which this document imposes no requirements" [`[defns.undefined]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined) If you access `[]` out of range, the standard imposes no requirements on the implementation, ergo the implementation *may* implement the behaviour `throw out_of_range()`

Comment: Invoking UB is not the same as specyfing whether implementation can or cannot declare the function to throw. That's like saying that the standard allows implementers to output stuff when invoking `operator[]` because it *could* exhibit UB. It's not the same.

Comment: No, I am saying that if a behaviour is undefined by the standard, it may still be defined by the implementation, and *by definition* it is an allowable behaviour in that circumstance

Answer (score 1):

The standard states w.r.t to operator `[]` for `std::array`:

> **26.3.7 Class template array [array]**
>
> 26.3.7.1 Class template array overview [[**array.overview**]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array#overview)
>
> ```
> namespace std {
> template <class T, size_t N>
> struct array {
> ...  
>
> // element access:
> constexpr reference operator[](size_type n);
> constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
> ```

As we can see they are **not** `noexcept`.

Whereas members like `data()` are clearly marked `noexcept`

```
constexpr T * data() noexcept;
constexpr const T * data() const noexcept;
```