# Given C++23 relaxations on constexpr, can't constexpr be the default?

Tags: c++, constexpr, language-design, c++23, constexpr-function

The keyword [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) enforced pretty tight restrictions on functions on its introduction into the C++11 standard. These restrictions were loosened with C++14 and C++20 (most noteworthy):

- C++14 allowed multiple `return` statements, `static_assert`s etc.
- C++20 allowed `try` and `asm`

C++23 further softens these restrictions. From what I can see in cppreference, `constexpr` for functions seems to only have the following meaning left:

- it must not be a coroutine
- for constructor and destructor, the class must have no virtual base classes
- For constexpr function templates and constexpr member functions of class templates, at least one specialization must satisfy the abovementioned requirements.

C++23 even removed the restriction that a constexpr function must be "evaluatable" at compile time for any type in [p2448r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html). From my understanding this completely removed the idea of a `constexpr` function to be evaluated at compile time.

Is that it? If so, how is a `constexpr` function even useful anymore?

Comment: It can be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @user253751 So can a none constexpr function, given the "as-if" clause. See also p2448r2: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html

Comment: In practice, if your function is constexpr then the compiler promises it *will* evaluate it at compile time, if at all possible, otherwise it merely makes a feeble attempt. Is this a language-lawyer question?

Comment: Stop thinking that the `constexpr` restrictions designate a set of functions, which has been replaced by a larger set.  The changes did not make any user-provided function `constexpr` which was not marked by the programmer.  Rather, the `constexpr` keyword defines a set of functions, and the language changes relaxed restrictions on how those functions can be implemented internally.

Comment: @user253751 *then the compiler promises it will evaluate it at compile time* is not true.  It promises that it can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @user253751: The compiler promises that it will evaluate it at compile time if it appears in a context where a compile-time constant is required (like initialization of a `constexpr` object)

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be an appropriate answer for a language-lawyer question but not for someone who is interested in actual programs and actual compilers.

Comment: @user253751: Actual programs can call `constexpr` functions in ways that will never be evaluated at compile-time, on any current or future compiler.

Comment: I think what you mean to ask: why do we still need to annotate functions as `constexpr`, not "how is a `constexpr` function even useful anymore?" (to which the obvious answer is: it's extremely useful to evaluate code at compile-time?)

Comment: Basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879475/why-cant-constexpr-just-be-the-default or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472359/why-do-we-need-to-mark-functions-as-constexpr. C++23 doesn't matter really, they could have decided that every function that satisfies the `constexpr` requirements would be automatically `constexpr` already in C++11 (and for lambdas that is actually how it was decided eventually).

Comment: Please keep in mind that https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html explicitly softened the restriction that it needs to be possible to evaluate the function at compile time.

Comment: One nice thing about having to decorate a constant function with `constexpr` is it enforces the constant expression requirements.  If you accidently do something non-constant you'll get a nice compiler error instead of the compile silently compiling the code and running it at run time.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, not since https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html was accepted. That's basically my biggest problem, I'll add that to the question itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you actually seem to ask is: why not make anything `constexpr` by default?

Because you might want others to not use a function at compile-time, to give you a possibility to switch to a non-constexpr implementation later.

Imagine this:

- You see a library function, which you'd like to use at compile-time.

  Let's say, `size_t RequiredBufferSize();`. If it happens to be constexpr, you can allocate the buffer on the stack, or something like that.
- You're not sure if it's supposed to work at compile-time, because there's no `constexpr` in our imaginary language.
- You try it, and it does work at compile-time. You start using it this way.

  Let's say the implementation was `{return 42;}`, which is `constexpr`.
- A new version of the library is released, the function no longer works at compile-time (e.g. the size is loaded from a config file).
- You complain to the developer, and he argues that the function was never intended to work at compile-time, and you relied on an implementation detail.

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer true in C++23 since https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html was accepted.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher Which part specifically? Notice that I'm talking about the opposite scenario (the paper basically suggests to automatically strip `constexpr` if it can't work, while you in your question seem to automatically add it if it can work).

Comment: It is now allowed to call none constexpr functions from constexpr functions, thus making the invocation at compile time impossible in all cases.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher Mhm, I didn't say otherwise.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher If the function is marked `constexpr` but actually isn't, there are no lasting consequences. Your code breaks, then the library developer fixes their bug, and it starts working again. But the opposite, if the function isn't marked `constexpr` but actually happens to be, would lock library developers into their implementation details.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher You could always have a call to a non-`constexpr` function in a `constexpr` function. But if you are actually evaluating the call to the non-`constexpr` function it is not a constant expression. Nothing about this changed. But as explained above, that's not relevant to the answer anyway.

Comment: So does `constexpr` for functions now more or less have a commentary function for other developers rather than applying any actual restrictions while compiling?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher It's the lack of `constexpr` that applies restrictions to the caller. Previously the presence of `constexpr` also applied restrictions to the implementation, but now only the first part remains.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this argument is pretty weak. How often have you written a library function that starts out being usable at compile-time and changes to being unusable at compile time? And why is that particular change in contract so important as to merit everyone having to annotate everything? As opposed to adding something like `std::not_usable_in_constant_expressions("nope :-p");` that's just a no-op that's unusuable in constant expressions.

Comment: Unrelatedly, that macro coroutine library is some serious black magic. Holy black cat is right.

Comment: @Barry *"How often have you written a library function"* I didn't, but I've seen it happen once: https://github.com/doctest/doctest/issues/473 Mhm, I like your idea more. *"some serious black magic"* Thank you. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Interesting example, but `SIGSTKSZ` wasn't a constexpr function :-)

Comment: "If the function is marked constexpr but actually isn't, there are no lasting consequences. Your code breaks, then the library developer fixes their bug, and it starts working again." - why is this a bug? A function marked `constexpr` _might_ be constant-evaluated, but you cannot say for sure. If there are no parameters, then probably yes, you can _expect_ it will be const-evaluated. But if there are non-zero parameters, some sets of parameters might yield const-evaluation and some - runtime evaluation. And there is no syntactic way to define these sets.

Comment: To me this makes application of `constexpr` on a function with parameters very confusing. In an imaginary language where `constexpr` is implicit, you would go with a simple comment which sets of parameters yield const-evaluation and which do not. With the same result as applying `constexpr` in actual C++23. Do you agree?