# Constexpr lambda by default?

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr, c++17

According to [n4487](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) and other c++17 references, there will be new lambda function specifier - `constexpr` , which if present *"explicitly specifies that the function call operator is a `constexpr` function."*. I understand the motivation about constant expressions in lambdas. What is interesting for me is point 4 of proposal which states:

> 4) If the `constexpr` specifier is omitted within the lambda-declarator, the function call operator (or template) is `constexpr` if it would satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` function.

This leads me to two questions:

1. Why do we need `constexpr` specifier? Looks like that whether the lambda call operator will be `constexpr` or not depends only on the fact will it "satisfy the requirements of a `constexpr` function", but not from  `constexpr` specifier presence.
2. If it is acceptable to have `constexpr` lambda by default, why isn't it proposed for other types of functions as well - for example global functions? What will be the impact if compiler starts to treat all functions which cover requirements as `constexpr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The `constexpr` qualifier makes it a *compile error* for the lambda to violate the requirements of `constexpr` functions. You use it when you explicitly *need* the lambda to be `constexpr`, so that you don't accidentally make it not `constexpr`.
2. [Asked and answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14472359/734069)