# Would it be sufficient for constexpr, consteval, and constinit to be definitions instead of keywords?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

It seems that the rules for the compile-time keywords: `constexpr`, `consteval` and `constinit` are defined well enough for compilers to warn if you misapply the label.

It would make sense that (much like inline) the compiler can, in all places, apply rules to determine if, in fact, code could have one of the compile-time keywords applied and, be forced, per language specification, to compile as much as possible as if the compile-time keywords had been applied.

Or, at a minimum, if a compile-time keyword is applied to a function and the code would have qualified with had the correct compile-time keywords been applied. Compile that function, as if all the functions called had the correct compile-time keywords.

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

consteval std::tuple<int, int> init1(int x, int y)
{
    return {x,y};
}

std::tuple<int, int>& foo1()
{
    static constinit std::tuple<int, int> x=init1(1,2);
    return x;
}

std::tuple<int, int> init2(int x, int y)
{
    return {x,y};
}

std::tuple<int, int>& foo2()
{
    static std::tuple<int, int> x=init2(1,2);
    return x;
}

static std::tuple<int, int> x3=init2(1,2);

std::tuple<int, int>& foo3()
{
    return x3;
}
```

see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/KrzGfnEo7

Note that init1/foo1 are fully specified with compile-time keywords and there is no need for a guard variable, since it is initialized completely (not just 0 filled).

The question is about why the compiler doesn't do the same in the cases of init2/foo2 or x3/foo3? Or more precisely why the compiler is allowed NOT to initialize fully at compile time.

EDIT (as per comment) see ([Why do we need to mark functions as constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14472359/103167)) `constexpr` would be required. I am concerned more with cases of `consteval` and `constinit`. Could the specification be modified to require trying to resolve code at compile-time and not failing because of the absence of `constexpr`? This would allow interface contracts to just use `constexpr` as per the related question.

Comment: Are you asking why `constexpr` isn't applied automatically?  (read https://stackoverflow.com/q/14472359/103167)  Or whether the compiler can perform compile-time optimization on code not using `constexpr`?  (It can.)

Comment: Yes, I understand since constexpr is optional. I was concerned more for places where I apply consteval or constinit and the compiler could allow it, independent of the existence of constexpr, etc., sorry if that wasn't clear. I'll see if I can edit for that to be clearer.

Comment: a compiler is allowed to apply any optimization as long as you cannot tell the difference. When a function can be evaluated at compile time then why should it not? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule.

Comment: The question wasn't "Can the compiler?", but rather "Why isn't the compiler required?"

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: "*Could the specification be modified to require trying to resolve code at compile-time and not failing because of the absence of `constexpr`?*" That is a matter of quality-of-implementation, not language specification.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: The compiler isn't required because of the Halting Problem.  Determining whether the evaluation could be completed at compile time (if allowed unlimited compile time) is in general undecidable.  Furthermore in cases where it is decidable, having to wait for the compiler to try and give up would be very wasteful and slow down the rebuild cycle horribly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, the failure of the compiler to optimize this particular case is QoI.  That the specification cannot say "try" is a well-known result of computer science.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am saying specifically, in the case where the evaluation of a constinit fails solely because of the lack of a constexpr or consteval keyword, why not have it succeed? It is going down no other path than had the keyword been there so this is not a Halting Problem, it is simply a syntax difference. No more or less calculations on the part of the compiler.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: I'm pretty sure you were asking why a variable not marked `constinit` doesn't have the initializer evaluated at compile time "if at all possible under the as-if rule", not why a variable that is marked `constinit` causes a compile-time error.  That one is a simple matter of contract.  The provider of the non-`constexpr`-marked function has reserved the right to do non-compile-time things in future implementations.

Comment: And now you've changed the question / moved the goalposts.

Comment: @BenVoigt  I was trying to clarify, but yes. I think it has changed, I will revert.

Comment: If it stays the way it is now I will close it as a duplicate of the first answer I linked in my first comment.  Which you should actually read.

Comment: Reverted to before edit.... (and yes I read)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: "*in the case where the evaluation of a constinit fails solely because of the lack of a constexpr or consteval keyword, why not have it succeed?*" Because that is literally why `constinit` was added to the language. That compile error is the whole point.

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you, that gave me the point of view I was missing. Unfortunate, but testing a contract makes sense. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: I did make it an answer. It's at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or, at a minimum, if a compile-time keyword is applied to a function and the code would have qualified with had the correct compile-time keywords been applied.

The basis of your question is the assumption that these keywords are just variations on a theme, that a function which could have some of them *ought to* have a specific one based on the properties within the function alone.

That's not reasonable.

For functions, any function which could be `constexpr` could also be `consteval`. The difference is that one *can* be called during constant expression evaluation, and the other *must* be called *only* during constant expression evaluation. This is not an intrinsic property of the function definition; it is about how the function is to be *used*.

The compiler should not override the decision of a programmer to be able to use a function at runtime just because the function definition just so happens to also be legit for `consteval`.

It should also be noted that there is the requirements of a function definition for a `consteval` function are the *same* as for a `constexpr` function.

It is also not possible to know if a function definition ought to be `constexpr` or not. Remember: while a `constexpr` function [explicitly forbids certain constructs from appearing in the definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3), it also permits you to have [certain constructs in the definition that aren't allowed to be evaluated during constant evaluation...](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5) so long as you never actually allow those code paths to be evaluated during constant evaluation. So there are many function definitions that just so happen to be valid for `constexpr` even if the programmer didn't intend for them to be evaluated at compile-time.

Lambdas get implicit `constexpr` definitions only because space in a lambda expression is at a premium.

For variables, implicit `constexpr` makes even less sense. A variable ought to be `constexpr` if you intend to use it in a constant expression later on. This requires it to have an initializer that is a constant expression. Implicit `constexpr` is a problem because you might start relying on the implicit `constexpr` rule, then change the initializer to no longer be a constant expression and get a strange error in the place where you used its `constexpr` properties.

It's better to make the user be explicit up-front than to misjudge what the user was trying to do and make a user think something is supposed to be valid when it wasn't intended.

And `constinit` is solely about ensuring that a user never accidentally uses a non-constant expression to initialize the variable. Making it implicit would make absolutely no sense, as changing the expression to no longer be a constant expression wouldn't cause compilation to fail. Compilers are smart enough to know when a variable is initialized with a constant expression and can decide how to handle that on its own.