# Compile-time or runtime detection within a constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, compile-time, c++17

I was excited when constexpr was introduced in C++11, but I unfortunately made optimistic assumptions about its usefulness. I assumed that we could use constexpr anywhere to catch literal compile-time constants or any constexpr result of a literal compile-time constant, including something like this:

```
constexpr float MyMin(constexpr float a, constexpr float b) { return a<b?a:b; }
```

Because qualifying a function's return type only as constexpr does not limit its usage to compile-time, and must also be callable at runtime, I figured that this would be a way to ensure that MyMin can only ever be used with compile-time evaluated constants, and this would ensure that the compiler would never allow its execution at runtime, freeing me to write an alternative more runtime friendly version of MyMin, ideally with the same name that uses a _mm_min_ss intrinsic, ensuring that the compiler won't generate runtime branching code. Unfortunately, function parameters cannot be constexpr, so it would seem that this cannot be done, unless something like this were possible:

```
constexpr float MyMin(float a, float b)
{
#if __IS_COMPILE_TIME__
    return a<b?a:b;
#else
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_min_ss(_mm_set_ss(a),_mm_set_ss(b)));
#endif
}
```

I have serious doubts that MSVC++ has anything like this at all, but I was hoping maybe GCC or clang have at least something to accomplish it, however unelegant it may look like.

Granted, the example I presented was very simplistic, but if you can use your imagination, there are many cases where you could feel free to do something like make extensive use of branching statements within a function that you know can only execute at compile time, because if it executed at runtime, performance would be compromised.

Comment: I make extensive use of templates for removing branches inside loops. Imagine that you have a branch inside a loop, you can remove this by adding an integer (=enum) template argument to the function in question. This is possible and has been possible using MSVC for years.

Comment: @JensMunk And how is that related to the question?

Comment: @plasmacel It's related to the question by providing a possible workaround for the problem the OP is describing.

Comment: It is very related. You can use a macro to decide whether an argument should be interpreted as a template or an ordinary argument. You can use for testing, switching on/off optimization. Same problem

Comment: @JensMunk - please, can you expand your comment in an answer (with working example)?

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP wants to detect whether a `constexpr` function is being evaluated at compile-time or runtime. On the other hand `a < b ? a : b` does no branching at all, the compiler will generate a conditional move instruction.

Comment: @plasmacel, MSVC++ will branch with float arguments unfortunately. Clang is smarter and will emit the minss instruction. And cmov only works on integers.

Comment: @plasmacel I anticipated that the OP wanted to ensure that something was evaluated compile-time and this is easy to achieve using templates, which is supported using MSVC++. My bad :-)

Comment: @Kumputer For floating-point arguments the compiler (targeting AVX and above) will implement a conditional move using `vcmpeqss` and `vblendvps` without any branching. For pre-AVX targets it will implement the same using `cmpeqss` `andps` `andnps` `orps`

Comment: [This old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235857/find-out-the-parameter-is-constexpr) is similar. It doesn't have a good answer as I write this, but perhaps one of these questions should be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 18):

It is possible to detect if a given function-call expression is a constant expression, and thereby select between two different implementations. Requires C++14 for the generic lambda used below.

(This answer grew out [this answer from @Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32398825/146041) to a question I asked last year).

I'm not sure how far I'm pushing the Standard. This is tested on clang 3.9, but causes g++ 6.2 to give an "internal compiler error". I'll send a bug report next week (if nobody else does it first!)

This first step is to move the `constexpr` implementation into a `struct` as a `constexpr static` method. More simply, you could leave the current `constexpr` as is and call it from a `constexpr static` method of a new `struct`.

```
struct StaticStruct {
    static constexpr float MyMin_constexpr (float a, float b) {
        return a<b?a:b;
    }
};
```

Also, define this (even though it looks useless!):

```
template<int>
using Void = void;
```

The basic idea is that `Void<i>` requires that `i` be a constant expression. More precisely, this following lambda will have suitable overloads only in certain circumstances:

```
auto l = [](auto ty)-> Void<(decltype(ty)::   MyMin_constexpr(1,3)   ,0)>{};
                                              \------------------/
                                               testing if this
                                               expression is a
                                               constant expression.
```

We can call `l` only if the argument `ty` is of type `StaticStruct` *and* if our expression of interest (`MyMin_constexpr(1,3)`) is a constant expression. If we replace `1` or `3` with non-constant arguments, then the generic lambda `l` will lose the method via SFINAE.

Therefore, the following two tests are equivalent:

> - Is `StaticStruct::MyMin_constexpr(1,3)` a *constant expression*?
> - Can `l` be called via `l(StaticStruct{})`?

It's tempting to simply delete `auto ty` and `decltype(ty)` from the above lambda. But that will give a hard error (in the non-constant case) instead of a nice substitution failure. We therefore use `auto ty` to get substitution failure (which we can usefully detect) instead of error.

This next code is a straightforward thing to return `std:true_type`
 if and only if `f` (our generic lambda) can be called with `a` (`StaticStruct`):

```
template<typename F,typename A>
constexpr
auto
is_a_constant_expression(F&& f, A&& a)
    -> decltype( ( std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)) , std::true_type{} ) )
{ return {}; }
constexpr
std::false_type is_a_constant_expression(...)
{ return {}; }
```

Next, a demonstration of it's use:

```
int main() {
    {
        auto should_be_true = is_a_constant_expression(
            [](auto ty)-> Void<(decltype(ty)::   MyMin_constexpr(1,3)   ,0)>{}
            , StaticStruct{});
        static_assert( should_be_true ,"");
    }
    {   
        float f = 3; // non-constexpr
        auto should_be_false = is_a_constant_expression(
            [](auto ty)-> Void<(decltype(ty)::   MyMin_constexpr(1,f)   ,0)>{}
            , StaticStruct{});
        static_assert(!should_be_false ,"");
    }
}
```

---

To solve your original problem directly, we could first define a macro to save repetition:

(I haven't tested this macro, apologies for any typos.)

```
#define IS_A_CONSTANT_EXPRESSION( EXPR )                \
     is_a_constant_expression(                          \
         [](auto ty)-> Void<(decltype(ty)::             \
              EXPR                         ,0)>{}       \
         , StaticStruct{})
```

At this stage, perhaps you could simply do:

```
#define MY_MIN(...)                                            \
    IS_A_CONSTANT_EXPRESSION( MyMin_constexpr(__VA_ARGS__) ) ? \
        StaticStruct :: MyMin_constexpr( __VA_ARGS__ )     :   \
                        MyMin_runtime  ( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

or, if you don't trust your compiler to optimize `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` through `?:`, then perhaps:

```
constexpr
float MyMin(std::true_type, float a, float b) { // called if it is a constant expression
    return StaticStruct:: MyMin_constexpr(a,b);
}
float MyMin(std::false_type, float , float ) { // called if NOT a constant expression
    return                MyMin_runtime(a,b);
}
```

with this macro instead:

```
#define MY_MIN(...)                                             \
  MyMin( IS_A_CONSTANT_EXPRESSION(MyMin_constexpr(__VA_ARGS__)) \
       , __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I really have to go now. Hope this answer helps. Feel free to make edits to this question, I'll probably be offline until Monday.

Comment: I've [reported this as a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78337) against gcc 6.2.0. I haven't had a chance to check this in any later gcc, apologies if this has already been fixed

Comment: Caveat is that `std::cout << MY_MIN(1, 3)` would use constant expression version whereas it is called in non constant expression (and so can be computed at runtime only (optimizer can work though)).

Answer (score 8):

> I figured that this would be a way to ensure that MyMin can only ever be used with compile-time evaluated constants, and this would ensure that the compiler would never allow its execution at runtime

Yes; there is a way.

And works with C++11 too.

Google-ing I've found a [strange poisoning way](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-xyi_NILkZZEZQT2VPY21BVTQ/edit) (by Scott Schurr): in short, the following

```
extern int no_symbol;

constexpr float MyMin (float a, float b)
 {
   return a != a ? throw (no_symbol)
                 : (a < b ? a : b) ;
 }

int main()
 {
   constexpr  float  m0 { MyMin(2.0f, 3.0f) }; // OK

   float  f1 { 2.0f };

   float  m1 { MyMin(f1, 3.0f) };  // linker error: undefined "no_symbol"
 }
```

If I understand well, the idea behind it is that if `MyMin()` is executed compile time, `throw(no_symbol)` is never used (`a != a` is ever false) so there is no need to use `no_symbol` that is declared `extern` but is never defined (and `throw()` can't be used compile time).

If you use `MyMin()` run-time, `throw(no_symbol)` is compiled and `no_symbol` gives an error in linking phase.

More generally speaking, there is [a proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3583.pdf) (ever from Scott Schurr) but I'm not aware of implementations.

**--- EDIT ---**

As pointed by T.C. (thanks!) this solution work (if works and when works) only because the compiler doesn't optimize at point to understand that `a != a` is ever false.

In particular, `MyMin()` works (without good optimizations) because, in the example, we're working with float numbers and `a != a` can be true if `a` is NaN, so it's more difficult for a compiler detect that the `throw()` part is unuseful. If `MyMin()` is a function for integers, the body can be written (with test `float(a) != float(a)` to try to obstruct the compliler optimizations) as

```
constexpr int MyMin (int a, int b)
 {
   return float(a) != float(a) ? throw (no_symbol)
                 : (a < b ? a : b) ;
 }
```

but isn't a real solution for a function where there ins't a "natural" throw-able error case.

When it's a natural error case that should give error (compiling or running), it's different: the compiler can't optimize and the trick work.

Example: if `MyMin()` return the minimun value between `a` and `b` but `a` and `b` are to be differents or `MyMin()` should give a compiler error (not a great example... I know), so

```
constexpr float MyMin (float a, float b)
 {
   return a != b ? throw (no_symbol)
                 : (a < b ? a : b) ;
 }
```

works because the compiler can't optimize `a != b` and must compile (giving linker error) the `throw()` part.

Comment: This is only a partial solution, but a clever one though.

Comment: @plasmacel - I'm agree; unfortunately isn't a my solution :( ; I've only found it.

Comment: I don't entirely understand why is this working: why is `a != a` true in runtime?

Comment: I can't generate the linker error using that code. Seems like compilers are wise to that trick. Tried on gcc6.2, clang3.9, and [ideone](http://ideone.com/YbamLw)

Comment: The optimizer will see through your trivial example, and `a != a` isn't optimized away only because of NaNs. This only works if `-ffast-math` etc. are not on and the value of `a` isn't visible to the optimizer.

Comment: @plasmacel - `a != a` isn't `true` at runtime (but it's true if `a` is `Nan`, if I understand well the T.C. comment) but the compiler (if optimizations are avoided) should compile and link the `throw()` part.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - I suppose that is a compiler parameters issue; [with Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oWROnjewMHaxpvXb) I ever get the error.

Comment: @T.C. - what do you think about `float(a) != float(a)` when `a` is an integer? Should work (without "-ffast-math")?

Comment: A trick that only works without optimization is mostly useless, and this whole trick depends on an ODR violation, so a program using it is formally meaningless. @max66 A sufficiently clever optimizer can notice that that cast can never produce an NaN.

Comment: @T.C. - Unfortunately you're right. Suggestions? I mean: do you know a way to impose the compilation of the `throw()` part (in the no-contstexpress case)?

Comment: @T.C. - I've edited my answer trying to report your objections.