# Generic lambda with trailing return type depending on variadic arguments in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

In C++14, you can do something like this:

```
struct Placeholder
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr static T fct(T val) { return val; }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int i{};
    auto fct = [](auto&& placeholder) -> decltype(placeholder.fct(i)) { return 5.5f; };
    static_assert(fct(Placeholder{}) == 5, "");
}
```

For the sake of the example, consider that Placeholder::fct is actually manipulating the input type to something else (in the present case the function call is useless).

On the other hand, in C++11, you can simulate generic lambdas by declaring a templated functor. In fact, I could simply pass i to the constructor and store it as a member, like so:

```
template<typename T>
class Functor
{
    T i;
public:
    constexpr Functor(T i) : i{ i } {}
    template<typename P>
    constexpr auto operator()(P&& placeholder) const -> decltype(placeholder.fct(i))
    {
        return 5.5f;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int i{};
    constexpr Functor<decltype(i)> fct(i);
    static_assert(fct(Placeholder{}) == 5, "");
}
```

The problem comes when we want the Placeholder to take a variadic number of arguments, like so:

```
struct Placeholder
{
    template<typename... T>
    constexpr static auto fct(T... val) -> typename std::common_type<T...>::type
    {
        return { /* Do something with the values */ };
    }
};
```

In fact, in C++14, we could simply pass the values directly to the lambda:

```
decltype(placeholder.fct(1, 2, 3))
```

However, in C++11, since we can't store a variadic number of members in a class, I don't see how I could achieve the exact same result. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't... understand what your question is. What are you actually trying to do? Your initial C++14 example and C++11 example aren't equivalent, so I can't extrapolate what the problem is.

Comment: How are they not equivalent? I don't see any other way in C++11 to achieve the same result...

Comment: As for my usage, I'm using the lambda with SFINAE to detect constexpr input (the lambda is not used as is obviously). It works well in C++14, but I'm trying to make it C++11 compatible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40413051/2950563 for a similar use case.

Comment: The lambda example doesn't capture anything. In the `Functor` example (not actually a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)), it has a member variable. Regardless, it would help your question a lot if it had a *clear problem statement* of what it is you can do in C++14 but are struggling with in C++11.

Comment: Yes I agree. It's not exactly how the lambda would have been generated in practice. By 'equivalent', I was meaning that the behavior was the same in both cases.

Comment: replace `T` with a `std::tuple<Ts...>`. Unpack the tuple into an argument list with the help of a c++11 equivalent of `std::index_sequence`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, a pure C++11 solution can be worked out from @RichardHodges 's idea. You need to recode `std::apply` by hand. To that end, you also need to recode `std::integer_sequence`, `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`. Let's start with that:

```
template <typename T, T... Is>
struct integral_sequence {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
using index_sequence = integral_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>;

template <typename Seq, typename T, T... el>
struct append_sequence;

template <typename T, T... el, T... Is>
struct append_sequence<integral_sequence<T, Is...>, T, el...> {
    using type = integral_sequence<T, Is..., el...>;
};

namespace details {

template <std::size_t N>
struct make_index_sequence_impl {
private:
    using seq = typename make_index_sequence_impl<N-1>::type;
public:
    using type = typename append_sequence<seq, std::size_t, N>::type;
};

template <>
struct make_index_sequence_impl<0u> {
    using type = index_sequence<0>;
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct make_index_sequence {
    using type = typename make_index_sequence_impl<N-1>::type;
};

template <>
struct make_index_sequence<0u> {
    using type = index_sequence<>;
};

} // namespace details

template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename details::make_index_sequence<N>::type;
```

Now, we can tackle the `apply` implementation. Its goal is to take a `tuple` as input and forward its content unpacked. For example, `apply([](int x, int y) { /* impl */ }, std::make_tuple(0, 2))` is equivalent to `[](int x, int y) { /* ... */ }(0, 2)`

To do that we first need to dispatch a tuple content to a functor using an `index_sequence`:

```
namespace details {

template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto apply_impl(F&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple, index_sequence<Is...>) -> decltype(std::forward<F>(ftor)(std::get<Is>(tuple)...)) {
    return std::forward<F>(ftor)(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
}

} // namespace details
```

Then, the exposed `apply` comes in:

```
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
template <typename F, typename Tuple>
auto apply(F&& ftor, Tuple&& tuple) -> decltype(details::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(ftor), std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::value>())){
    return details::apply_impl(std::forward<F>(ftor), std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::value>());
}
```

Now we can get the behavior you desired by storing a tuple inside your class and using apply to dispatch its content to your `placeholder` functor:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Functor {
    std::tuple<Ts...> is;
public:
    constexpr Functor(Ts... ts) : is(std::make_tuple(ts...)) {}
    template <typename P>
    constexpr auto operator()(P&& placeholder) -> decltype(apply(std::forward<P>(placeholder), is)) {
        return apply(std::forward<P>(placeholder), is);
    }
};
```

Putting it all together with some examples leads to this [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82a246112c17eb53)

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20441189/1023390) for C++14 implementation of `std::apply()`.