# constexpr string-literal checking: short syntax, no runtime possibility

Tags: c++, runtime, constexpr, compile-time-type-checking, constexpr-function

### EDIT: Renamed, as my final solution does not use a poisoning method.

I'm looking for a way to prevent a constexpr method from being called at runtime.  I'm writing a function that accepts a string literal, so I cannot simply use a NTTP as a way to require a `constexpr` parameter:

```
template<const char* str>
auto func() {...}
```

Because then even legitimate constexpr uses become cumbersome, requiring values to have static linkage, and you can't feed in a string literal.  I want to do:

```
constexpr auto func(const char* str) {...}
```

The reason is because I check the string against a list of values, and want to STATICALLY check that the parameter is contained in the allowed set.  I can do this easily: by just `throw()`'ing in a `constexpr` function, you can cause a compile-time error.  But I do not want the possibility of generating production code with some branch that causes the program to exit at runtime. That would cause a major problem in my field; this feature is a nice-to-have in a program that does "other important stuff" and bad things happen if the program terminates.

I read about a whole bunch of possible ways to do this:

1. Use C++20 `consteval` - don't have C++20
2. Use C++20 `std::is_constant_evaluated` - don't have C++20
3. Poison the method at runtime by returning a result to an undefined symbol (e.g. `extern int i` that never gets defined).  The compiler never creates code which returns that symbol if the method is called at compile-time, but it does if the method is called at runtime, resulting in a link error.  Works, but ugly linker error; not my favorite.  A version of that is shown in my post here: [Constexpr functions not called at compile-time if result is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63422516/13080413).
4. In C++17, `noexcept` gets automatically added onto any call to a `constexpr` function that actually gets called in a `constexpr` context.  So you can do `noexcept(foo(1))` vs `noexcept(foo(i))` for `constexpr int foo(int i)` (not explicitly declared `noexcept`) to detect whether `i` causes the call to be `constexpr`/not.  But you can't do that from within a `constexpr` function that has accepted some parameter - you need to do it from the call-site. So: probably requires a helper MACRO (not my favorite but it works).
5. Create a lambda whose return type is invalid if certain variables outside the scope of the lambda are not `constexpr`.  This post goes into detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40413051

So I'm leaning towards using #3 or #4 + a macro, but ***this post is about #5 ***, or totally new ideas.

Can anyone come up with a way to do #5 without a lambda, for example?  After that, I want to see if I can come up with a way to use it within the `constexpr` function itself rather than requiring it to be used from the call-site.  For now, just try to poison a `constexpr` function if it is called at runtime, forget about "detecting" whether the function call is `constexpr`.

I can re-create the results of #5 by creating a lambda in `main` as the author did, but that's not actually very useful, and I'm still not convinced that it's fully legal.  To start with, anything that can be done with a lambda can be done without a lambda -- right???  I can't even get the original author's method to work without a lambda.  That seems like a first required step to get it to work outside of `main()`.

Below are a couple ideas I've tried to recreate #5 without a lambda.  Live example with a billion more permutations, none of which work: https://onlinegdb.com/B1oRjpTGP

```
// Common
template<int>
using Void = void;

// Common
struct Delayer {
    constexpr auto delayStatic(int input) { return input; }
};

// Attempt 1
template<typename PoisonDelayer>
constexpr auto procurePoison(int i) {
    struct Poison {
        // error: use of parameter from containing function
        // constexpr auto operator()() const -> Void<(PoisonDelayer::delayStatic(i), 0)> {}
    } poison;
    
    return poison;
}

// Attempt 2
struct PoisonInnerTemplate {
    const int& _i;

    // Internal compiler error / use of this in a constexpr
    template<typename PoisonDelayer>
    auto drink() const -> Void<(PoisonDelayer::delayStatic(_i), 0)> {}
};

int main()
{
    auto attempt1 = procurePoison<Delayer>(1);
    
    constexpr int i = 1;
    auto attempt2 = PoisonInnerTemplate{i};
    attempt2.drink<Delayer>();

    return 0;
}
```

One more thing: I toyed with the idea of making a pre-defined list of allowed tags (wrap the string in a struct so it can be a NTTP), and putting them in some kind of container, and then having a method to retrieve them.  The problems are: (1) the call-site syntax gets quite verbose to use them, (2) although it'd be fine for the call-site to use a syntax like `MyTags::TAG_ONE`, my program needs to be able to know the full set of tags, so they need to be in an array or a template variable, (3) using an array doesn't work, because getting an array element produces an `rvalue`, which doesn't have linkage, so can't be fed as a NTTP, (4) using a template variable with explicit specialization to define each tag requires the template variable to be global-scope, which doesn't work well for me...

This is about the best I can do - I think it's kind of ugly...:

```
struct Tag {
    const char* name;
};

template<auto& tag>
void foo() {}

struct Tags {
    static constexpr Tag invalid = {};
    static constexpr Tag tags[] = {{"abc"}, {"def"}};

    template<size_t N>
    static constexpr Tag tag = tags[N];
    
    template<size_t N = 0>
    static constexpr auto& getTag(const char* name) {
        if constexpr(N<2) {
            if(string_view(name)==tag<N>.name) {
                return tag<N>;
            } else {
                return getTag<N+1>(name);
            }
        } else {
            return invalid;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<Tags::getTag("abc")>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AdrianMole , the original post was hideous when I re-read it ;-) Totally re-wrote it, plus shortened the billion permutations in the example code.

Comment: As I understand  #5 allows to detect from outside of constexpr function if its parameter are constexpr and can be used in constant expression, but not if we are actually in a contant expression or not

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, as written in the original author's post, you essentially just detect if the parameters are `constexpr` or not, from outside of the `constexpr` function.  And the syntax is definitely uglier than #3 or #4.  But I was hoping that some variant of this or some new idea might work from within the `constexpr` function, or at least have a clean syntax.

Comment: *"or totally new ideas."* one possible way, as you works with string literal is to replace them with char_sequence: `template<char ... cs>
auto func(std::integer_sequence<char, cs...>) {...}` gcc/clang has extension to create udl for c-strings (else I got a MACRO solution)

Comment: So good idea, but how would the call-site syntax look?  For example this works `func(integer_sequence<char, 'a', 'b', 'c'>{});` but I'm trying to think how to use a UDL to make an `integer_sequence<char, input>`... Like, this doesn't work: `constexpr auto operator"" _TAG(const char* name) { return integer_sequence<char, name[0], name[1], name[2]>{}; }` because `name` isn't `constexpr`.

Comment: @Jarod42, I think there is a C++20 way to use a UDL with a string literal that gets treated as `constexpr` but are you aware of another way?

Comment: @Sean: see [ensure-that-char-pointers-always-point-to-the-same-string-literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866964/ensure-that-char-pointers-always-point-to-the-same-string-literal/58868005#58868005) (ise gcc/clang extension) or [string-interning-at-compiletime-for-profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288847/string-interning-at-compiletime-for-profiling/50289055#50289055) (use MACRO) for way to create the sequence from literal c-string.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, I'll ask if we are allowed to use that extension.  We use Clang with C++17, and I think we'd need some kind of approval to use other extensions, but who knows, maybe I can.  That'd be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own answer, which checks that a string literal is within an allowed set at COMPILE-TIME, then performs an action based upon the value of that string.  No poisoning of `constexpr` functions is needed, and there are still no cumbersome requirements to provide string literals with static linkage.

Credit goes to Jarod42 for "shorthand option 2", which uses a `gcc` extension for string template user-defined literals, which is part of C++20 but not C++17.

I think I'm happy enough with any of the three "shorthand" call-site syntaxes.  I would still welcome any alternatives or improvements, or pointers on what I messed up.  Perfect forwarding, etc. is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Live demo: https://onlinegdb.com/S1K_7sb7D

```
// Helper for Shorthand Option 1 (below)
template<typename Singleton>
Singleton* singleton;

// Helper to store string literals at compile-time
template<typename ParentDispatcher>
struct Tag {
    using Parent = ParentDispatcher;
    const char* name;
};

// ---------------------------------
// DISPATCHER:
// ---------------------------------
// Call different functions at compile-time based upon
// a compile-time string literal.
// ---------------------------------

template<auto& nameArray, typename FuncTuple>
struct Dispatcher {
    FuncTuple _funcs;
    
    using DispatcherTag = Tag<Dispatcher>;
    
    template<size_t nameIndex>
    static constexpr DispatcherTag TAG = {nameArray[nameIndex]};
    
    static constexpr DispatcherTag INVALID_TAG = {};

    Dispatcher(const FuncTuple& funcs) : _funcs(funcs) {
        singleton<Dispatcher> = this;
    }

    template<size_t nameIndex = 0>
    static constexpr auto& tag(string_view name) {
        if(name == nameArray[nameIndex]) {
            return TAG<nameIndex>;
        } else {
            if constexpr (nameIndex+1 < nameArray.size()) {
                return tag<nameIndex+1>(name);
            } else {
                return INVALID_TAG;
            }
        }
    }

    static constexpr size_t index(string_view name) {
        for(size_t nameIndex = 0; nameIndex < nameArray.size(); ++nameIndex) {
            if(name == nameArray[nameIndex]) {
                return nameIndex;
            }
        }
        return nameArray.size();
    }
    
    constexpr auto& operator()(const char* name) const {
        return tag(name);
    }

    template<auto& tag, typename... Args>
    auto call(Args... args) const {
        static constexpr size_t INDEX = index(tag.name);
        static constexpr bool VALID = INDEX != nameArray.size();
        static_assert(VALID, "Invalid tag.");

        return get<INDEX*VALID>(_funcs)(args...);
    }
};

template<auto& nameArray, typename FuncTuple>
auto makeDispatcher(const FuncTuple& funcs) {
    return Dispatcher<nameArray, FuncTuple>(funcs);
}

// ---------------------------------
// SHORTHAND: OPTION 1
// ---------------------------------
// Use a singleton pattern and a helper to let a tag be associated with a
// specific dispatcher, so that the call-site need not specify dispatcher twice
// ---------------------------------

template<auto& tag, typename... Args>
auto call(Args... args) {
    using Tag = remove_reference_t<decltype(tag)>;
    using ParentDispatcher = typename Tag::Parent;
    static auto dispatcher = singleton<ParentDispatcher>;

    return dispatcher->template call<tag>(args...);
}

// ---------------------------------
// SHORTHAND: OPTION 2
// ---------------------------------
// Use a string template user-defined literal operator to shorten call-site syntax
// gcc supports this as an extension implementing proposal N3599 (standardized in C++20)
// If warnings occur, try pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu-string-literal-operator-template"
// ---------------------------------

// Need characters to be in contiguous memory on the stack (not NTTPs) for TAG_FROM_LITERAL
template<char... name>
constexpr char NAME_FROM_LITERAL[] = {name..., '\0'};

// Don't need to specify Dispatcher with user-defined literal method; will use dispatcher.check<>()
struct TagFromLiteral {};

// Need to have a constexpr variable with linkage to use with dispatcher.check<>()
template<char... name>
constexpr Tag<TagFromLiteral> TAG_FROM_LITERAL = {NAME_FROM_LITERAL<name...>};

// Create a constexpr variable with linkage for use with dispatcher.check<>(), via "MyTag"_TAG
template<typename Char, Char... name>
constexpr auto& operator"" _TAG() {
    return TAG_FROM_LITERAL<name...>;
}

// ---------------------------------
// SHORTHAND: OPTION 3
// ---------------------------------
// Use a macro so the call-site need not specify dispatcher twice
// ---------------------------------

#define DISPATCH(dispatcher, name) dispatcher.call<dispatcher(name)>

// ---------------------------------
// COMMON: TEST FUNCTIONS
// ---------------------------------

bool testFunc1(int) { cout << "testFunc1" << endl; }
bool testFunc2(float) { cout << "testFunc2" << endl; }
bool testFunc3(double) { cout << "testFunc3" << endl; }

static constexpr auto funcs = make_tuple(&testFunc1, &testFunc2, &testFunc3);
static constexpr auto names = array{"one", "two", "three"};

int main()
{
    // Create a test dispatcher
    auto dispatcher = makeDispatcher<names>(funcs);

    // LONG-HAND: call syntax: a bit verbose, but operator() helps
    dispatcher.call<dispatcher("one")>(1);
    
    // SHORTHAND OPTION 1: non-member helper, singleton maps back to dispatcher
    call<dispatcher("one")>(1);

    // SHORTHAND OPTION 2: gcc extension for string UDL templates (C++20 standardizes this)
    dispatcher.call<"one"_TAG>(1);

    // SHORHAND OPTION 3: Macro
    DISPATCH(dispatcher, "one")(1);

    return 0;
}
```