# constexpr constructor not called as constexpr for implicit type conversion

Tags: c++, string, runtime, constexpr, constexpr-function

I made some code which is capable of dispatching to a function based upon the call-site providing a string associated with a given function (via a `tuple` of function pointers and a parallel array).  Instead of accepting a string directly, the dispatch function accepts a `Callable` type, where a `const char*` is convertible to a `Callable`.

The constructor of `Callable` is `constexpr`, and looks up a function from the noted `tuple` with a basic recursive search.  I've verified that the constructor is capable of working correctly and creating a `constexpr` `Callable` (example included). Since the dispatch function receives the arguments to pass to the `Callable`'s `operator()`, I know the expected function signature of the `Callable`'s `operator()` at the time I create it.

I'm trying to perform two checks at compile-time, when they can be done at compile-time.  First, I check that the provided string exists in the pre-defined array of strings, at all.  Second, I check that the signature of the function associated with that string matches the expected signature from the `tuple` of function pointers.  I create "friendly" error messages at compile-time by `throw()`'ing within the `constexpr` method that looks up the function.

I've verified that by creating a `constexpr` callable, I get the expected error messages at compile-time.  This works.  What doesn't work is getting compile-time messages if I use my `Dispatcher` directly, letting the call-site convert a string into a `Callable`.  I know that when I use runtime parameters, my dispatch function won't be called in a `constexpr` context - I intentionally didn't make that function `constexpr`; the point is to call it with runtime values.  But **I thought that implicit conversions "happen at the call-site"**, not within the called function.

Therefore, I thought that in a call like `dispatcher("one", 1)` (which calls the first function with a parameter of 1) would look like: "one" gets converted to a `Callable` **at the call-site**, then a call gets made as `dispatcher(Callable("one"), 1)`.  That would mean that the `constexpr` constructor ***could*** be used, at least.  In my experience, as long as you don't **ignore** the result of a `constexpr` call, the call is made as `constexpr` if it can be, else it is made as runtime.  See [Constexpr functions not called at compile-time if result is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63422516/12854372).  This isn't happening -- **the conversion constructor is being called at runtime** when the conversion happens within a call to my dispatch function!

Does anyone know of a way I can change my code to get the conversion constructor to be called at compile-time if it can be???  I found a totally different solution to solve this general class of problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63568349/12854372), but frankly I like the syntax of the code below better, if I could get it working.

I'm not going to include the above code in the body of this post, but rather include a more canonical example that demonstrates the behavior and also shows the behavior I saw in the post I referenced above, all-in-one.

Live demo of the below: https://onlinegdb.com/r1s1OE77v

Live demo of my "real" problem, if interested: https://onlinegdb.com/rJCQ2bGXw

First the "test fixtures":

```
// Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40410624/12854372

// In a constexpr context, ContextIsConstexpr1(size_t) always
// simply sets _s to 1 successfully.

extern bool no_symbol_s_is_zero;

struct ContextIsConstexpr1 {
    size_t _s;

    constexpr ContextIsConstexpr1(size_t s) : _s(s ? 1 : no_symbol_s_is_zero) {}
};

// In a constexpr context, ContextIsConstexpr2(size_t) will cause
// a compile-time error if 0 is passed to the constructor

struct ContextIsConstexpr2 {
    size_t _s;

    constexpr ContextIsConstexpr2(size_t s) : _s(1) {
        if(!s) {
            throw logic_error("s is zero");
        }
    }
};

// Accept one of the above. By using a CONVERSION constructor
// and passing in a size_t parameter, it DOES make a difference.

ContextIsConstexpr1 foo(ContextIsConstexpr1 c) { return c; }
ContextIsConstexpr2 bar(ContextIsConstexpr2 c) { return c; }
```

Now the test code:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t CONST = 1;
    #define TEST_OBVIOUS_ONES false
    
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 1: result is compile-time, param is compile-time
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    #if TEST_OBVIOUS_ONES
    
    // Compile-time link error iif s==0 w/ any optimization (duh)
    constexpr auto test1_1 = ContextIsConstexpr1(CONST);
    cout << test1_1._s << endl;

    // Compile-time throw iif s==0 w/ any optimization (duh)
    constexpr auto test1_2 = ContextIsConstexpr2(CONST);
    cout << test1_2._s << endl;

    #endif

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 2: result is runtime, param is compile-time
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Compile-time link error iif s==0 w/ any optimization ***See below***
    auto test2_1 = ContextIsConstexpr1(CONST);
    cout << test2_1._s << endl;

    // Runtime throw iif s==0 w/ any optimization
    // NOTE: Throw behavior is different than extern symbol behavior!!
    auto test2_2 = ContextIsConstexpr2(CONST);
    cout << test2_2._s << endl;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 3: Implicit conversion
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Compile-time link error if (1) s==0 w/ any optimization *OR* (2) s>0 w/ low optimization!!
    // Note: New s>0 error due to implicit conversion ***See above***
    auto test3_1 = foo(CONST);
    cout << test3_1._s << endl;

    // Runtime throw iif s==0 w/ any optimization
    auto test3_2 = bar(CONST);
    cout << test3_2._s << endl;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 4: result is ignored, param is compile-time
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Compile-time link error w/ any 's' iif low optimization
    // Note: no error w/ s==0 with high optimization, new error w/ s>0 by ignoring result ***See above***
    ContextIsConstexpr1{CONST};

    // Runtime throw iif s==0 w/ any optimization
    ContextIsConstexpr2{CONST};

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get runtime input, can't optimize this for-sure
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    #if TEST_OBVIOUS_ONES

    size_t runtime;
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> runtime;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 5: result is runtime, param is runtime
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Compile-time link error w/ any 's' w/ any optimization (duh)
    auto test5_1 = ContextIsConstexpr1(runtime);
    cout << test5_1._s << endl;

    // Runtime throw iif s==0 w/ any optimization (duh)
    auto test5_2 = ContextIsConstexpr2(runtime);
    cout << test5_2._s << endl;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Test 6: result is ignored, param is runtime
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // Compile-time link error w/ any 's' w/ any optimization (duh)
    ContextIsConstexpr1{runtime};

    // Runtime throw iif s==0 w/ any 's' w/ any optimization (duh)
    ContextIsConstexpr2{runtime};

    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way I can change my code to get the conversion constructor to be called at compile-time if it can be

As I said in linked posted, call of `constexpr` functions at compile time is done **only** in constant expression.

Parameters are not constexpr.

One workaround would be to use MACRO:

```
#define APPLY_DISPATCHER(dispatcher, str, ...) \
    do { \
        constexpr callable_type_t<decltype(dispatcher),  decltype(make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))> callable(str); \
        (dispatcher)(callable, __VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)
```

with

```
template <typename Dispatcher, typename Tuple> struct callable_type;

template <typename Dispatcher, typename ... Ts>
struct callable_type<Dispatcher, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = typename Dispatcher::template Callable<Ts...>;
};

template <typename Dispatcher, typename Tuple> 
using callable_type_t = typename callable_type<Dispatcher, Tuple>::type;
```

With usage:

```
APPLY_DISPATCHER(dispatcher, "one", 1);
APPLY_DISPATCHER(dispatcher, "a", 1); // Fail at compile time as expected
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ryEPbrf7P).

But not really better than proposed `dispatcher.dispatch(MAKE_CHAR_SEQ("a"), 1);` (or with extension `dispatcher.dispatch("a"_cs, 1);`) (providing dispatch overload to be able to create `constexpr` `Callable`).

Comment: Thanks again @Jarod42.  But before I mark this as answered, can you reconcile your statement "... is done only in constant expression" with the results of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63422516/12854372 ? (Or you can skip the post and see the live demo at https://www.onlinegdb.com/rJao0RNGP)  It seems that if the results of a `constexpr` call are saved EVEN in a runtime variable, in that code, the function was called as `constexpr`.  Weird that the results seem to be different - I wonder if this is the land of undefined behavior???

Comment: Program is ill formed (NDR), it is just that optimizer remove some code including `no_symbol`, even when no `constexpr` [Demo](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/rJao0RNGP) (`-O2` added) so we don't see the issue.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  But alas, I got the same results from your demo link -- `auto result2` was a `constexpr` call even with `-O2`.  I tried setting `-O2` myself in both `onelinegdb` and `wandbox` : https://wandbox.org/permlink/0rtieqf1SxSykQI7 will try `godbolt` in a minute.

Comment: Changed the body of my post to show the above more "canonical" example.  I think it's easier to see the mystery by showing the results of the old post side-by-side with the results using implicit conversion.  In the "old post" results, the behavior is independent of optimization level.  With implicit conversion, it's not.

Comment: It is not a constexpr, but optimized, similar issue with [why-does-c-stdmin-cant-use-a-static-field-as-its-parameter-when-compile-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575194/why-does-c-stdmin-cant-use-a-static-field-as-its-parameter-when-compile-on): Your diagnostic is "hidden" by optimizer (but as it is ill-formed NDR, error message is optional anyway...).

Comment: Marked as answered - thanks.  After giving it a fair fight, I couldn't get those "tricks" to do a whole lot that was useful.  I agree with you, there are better alternatives that we discussed on the earlier post.