# why does c++ std::min can't use a static field as its parameter when compile on O0?

Tags: c++, g++, std

same code, compile with O0, it will report an error:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : test.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;
class foo{

      static const int64_t MAX_THREAD_NUM = 10 * 1000;


public:
      void test();
};

void foo::test(){
    int64_t a = 100;
//  int64_t tmp = MAX_THREAD_NUM;
//  int64_t min = std::min(tmp, a);


    int64_t min = std::min(MAX_THREAD_NUM, a);
    cout << min << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.o" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"

g++  -o "test"  ./src/test.o   
./src/test.o: In function `foo::test()':
/home/foo/eclipse-workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:27: undefined reference to `foo::MAX_THREAD_NUM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/foo/eclipse-workspace/test/Debug/../src/test.cpp:27: undefined reference to `foo::MAX_THREAD_NUM'
```

but with O2 flag, it can compile succeed.

```
g++ -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.o" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.cpp"
g++  -o "test"  ./src/test.o
```

g++ version:
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

Comment: sloppy speaking all your code does is to print `!!!Hello World!!!` when you turn on optimizations compiler realizes that and ignores problems in code that is irrelevant for what the code actually does

Comment: @idclev463035818 My guess would be that the compiler, as an optimization, simply inlines the literal value of `MAX_THREAD_NUM` to the `std::min(...)` call, such that `MAX_THREAD_NUM` is no longer ODR-used (in the sense of the generated assembly code; the code is still ill-formed, NDR).

Comment: @dfri my guess was that `foo` is removed alltogether, but I was wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/nKnTdq

Comment: You should include `<algorithm>`.

Comment: [OT]: *"`using namespace std;`"*, but you have anyway to type `std::min` as you use local var `min`...

Answer (score 4):

Program is ill-formed no diagnostic required (NDR) as you break One Definition Rule (ODR) by not providing definition of ODR-used symbol (`std::min` takes its argument by reference).

The optimizer removes that unused code and lets you think it is correct.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `constexpr` (for the static data member) in this context.

Comment: I take some test, let the foo::test() bee called by main. It change nothing.  O2 can compile succeed,  O0 report the same error: "undefined reference to `foo::MAX_THREAD_NUM'"

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @dfri, compiler inlines `MAX_THREAD_NUM`. If we change it to `inline static const int64_t MAX_THREAD_NUM = 10 * 1000;`, it will compile fine on `O0`. Otherwise, declare but define the variable outside of the class, or mark it `constexpr` instead of `const`. Using a static const integral member needs definition if it's used where a non-const integral is needed.

```cpp
class foo {
      static const int64_t MAX_THREAD_NUM;
      ...
};
const int64_t foo::MAX_THREAD_NUM = 10 * 1000;
```

Comment: Note that where the static data member is _initialized_ is not of essence here, it is whether it is _defined_ or not, as it is ODR-used by `std::min()`. You could still initialize it in-class as long as a definition (`const int64_t foo::MAX_THREAD_NUM;`) follows.

Comment: Correct. Edited.